# Prove that $g^{n+m} = g^ng^m$

Tags: group-theory

Show that $g^{n+m} = g^ng^m$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Here is my proof:
Let G be a group let g be any element in G
For $0\le n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ 
By generalized associativity,
$$g^{n+m}=g.....g (n+m\quad many\quad g),$$
$$g^n=g.....g (n\quad many\quad g)$$ and 
$$g^m=g.....g (m\quad many\quad g)$$ for all $ g\in G and 0\le n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore g^{n+m} = g^ng^m$

For $0\gt n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Since $0\gt n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\quad$ implies $\quad 0\lt -n,-m\in\mathbb{Z} $ 
thus,by generalized associativity,
$$g^{-n-m}=g.....g (-n-m\quad many\quad g),$$
$$g^{-n}=g.....g (-n\quad many\quad g)$$ and 
$$g^{-m}=g.....g (-m\quad many\quad g)$$ for all $ g\in G and 0\le -n,-m\in\mathbb{Z} $

$\therefore g^{-n-m} = g^{-n}g^{-m}$

For $0\gt n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\lt m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Since $0\gt n \in\mathbb{Z}\quad$ implies $\quad 0\lt -n\in\mathbb{Z} $ 
thus,by generalized associativity,
$$g^{-n+m}=g.....g (-n+m\quad many\quad g),$$
$$g^{-n}=g.....g (-n\quad many\quad g)$$ and 
$$g^m=g.....g (m\quad many\quad g)$$ for all $ g\in G and 0\le -n,m\in\mathbb{Z} $

$\therefore g^{-n+m} = g^{-n}g^{m}$

Lastly, for $0\lt n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\gt m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Since $0\gt m\in\mathbb{Z}\quad$ implies $\quad 0\lt -m\in\mathbb{Z} $ 
thus,by generalized associativity,
$$g^{n-m}=g.....g (n-m\quad many\quad g),$$
$$g^n=g.....g (n\quad many\quad g)$$ and 
$$g^{-m}=g.....g (-m\quad many\quad g)$$ for all $ g\in G and 0\le n,-m\in\mathbb{Z} $

$\therefore g^{n-m} = g^{n}g^{-m}$
and we are done. Isn't it a bit too long? A better approach?

Comment: Can't we just use simple logic here? Like, g is operated with itself for n+1 times in LHS and expanding RHS also we get the same.

Comment: Once you have done the first case $0\leq m,n$, you can avoid repeating all the work : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150174/properties-in-group-gnm-gngm?rq=1

Comment: @ArnaudD. actually I didn't understand the logic there, and that's why asked to improve mine instead

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two-pence worth.

Define $g^0=e \in G$ the identity, then
\begin{align}
g^{m+0} &= g^m \\
&=g^m e \\
&=g^mg^0
\end{align}
as claimed. now take $m > 1$ such that
\begin{align}
g^{m+1} &= g^mg \\
&=g^mg^1
\end{align}
Also with $m > 0$
\begin{align}
g^{-m}g^1 &= (g^{-1})^mg^1 \\
&=(g^{-1})^{m-1}g^{-1}g^1 \\
&=(g^{-1})^{m-1} \\
&= g^{-m+1}
\end{align}
That is, $\forall \,m \in \mathbb{Z},\,g^{m+1}=g^mg $. Now this is the case for $n=1$ in the proof by induction stating that for $n \geq 1\, g^{m+n}=g^mg^n$. State that for some $k \geq 1$ that $g^{m+k}=g^mg^k$ is true, and seek similar argument for $g^{m+k+1}=g^mg^{k+1}$ etc.